# Add a filter to a query with a date_histogram and aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to display a table of units sold this year by month by category.
For example:

```
2015      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr May  Jun  Jul  Aug
category1  19   25   30   51  12   10    0    0
category2 105  110  125  131 209  233  310   80
category3  33   35   37    0   0    0    0    0
```

Here's my query.  Note that I'm missing the "this year" requirement.  How do I add it?  Adding a filter as the first child of "doc" gives an error: Found two aggregation type definitions in [doc]

```
{
    "doc": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "sale_createdDateTime",
            "interval": "month",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "extended_bounds": {
                 "min": "2015-01-01",
                 "max": "2015-12-31"
             }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "per_category": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "product_category"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your current aggregation within the [filter Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html). So the filter is not the first child of `doc`, but the first child of `aggs`. then, you have a nested `aggs` with your current aggregation. The result should be somewhat similar to :

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "per_category": {
            "filtered_agg": {
                "filter": {
                    /*YEAR FILTER HERE*/
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "nested_terms_agg": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "product_category"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(**NOTE:** `filtered_agg` and `nested_terms_agg` are just names I chose)